# Creating the After Insert trigger on multiple rows

Tags: sql-server, triggers, dml

I habe two tables -> Product(ProductID pk, ProductName) and ProductPublication(ProductID fk, ProductName added by denormalization).
I have to create After insert trigger on ProductPublication table that will insert/update ProductName in ProductPublication table, but it needs to work on multiple row insert. Any help?

```
CREATE TABLE [Product] ( 
[Product_ID] [int] NOT NULL, 
[ProductName] [nvarchar] (20) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY ([Product_ID]));

CREATE TABLE [ProductPublication] (
[ProductPublication_ID] [int] NOT NULL,
[Product_ID] [int] NOT NULL,
[ProductName] [nvarchar] (20) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY ([ProductPublication_ID],[Product_ID]),
FOREIGN KEY ([Product_ID]) REFERENCES [Product] ([Product_ID]));
```

These insert command bellow are working

```
INSERT [dbo].[Product] VALUES (1,N'Name1');
INSERT [dbo].[Product] VALUES (2,N'Name2');


INSERT [dbo].[ProductPublication] VALUES (1,1,'Name1');
INSERT [dbo].[ProductPublication] VALUES (1,2,'Name1');
INSERT [dbo].[ProductPublication] VALUES (2,1,'Name1');
INSERT [dbo].[ProductPublication] VALUES (2,2,'Name2');


DELETE FROM ProductPublication WHERE ProductPublication_ID in (1,2);
```

And this single insert command is not working.

```
INSERT [dbo].[ProductPublication] VALUES (1,1,'Name1'), 
(1,2,'Name2'),(2,1,'Name3'),(2,2,'Name4');
```

When i try to insert with multiple insert commands the trigger fails, so that means i need to create the trigger that will work with multiple insert rows.

This is the trigger i created, but that only works with one set of insert values:

```
CREATE TRIGGR [dbo].[TR_ProductPublication_Insert] on [dbo]. 
[ProductPublication]
AFTER INSERT AS 
SET NOCOUNT ON
   BEGIN
   UPDATE prodpub 
      SET ProductName = (SELECT ProductName from Product
      WHERE Product_ID = (SELECT Product_ID from inserted))
      FROM ProductPublication prodpub 
      JOIN inserted i 
      ON prodpub.Product_ID = i.Product_ID;
   END
```

I am using SQL server 2017.

THE SOLUTION - The correct trigger is :

```
 UPDATE prodpub 
      SET ProductName = (SELECT ProductName 
      from Product
      WHERE Product_ID = prodpub.Product_ID)
      FROM ProductPublication prodpub 
      JOIN inserted i 
      ON prodpub.Product_ID = i.Product_ID;
   END
```

Comment: @Akina ProductPublication also have ProductPublicationID, pk column. 
When i try to do this -> 
INSERT INTO ProductPublication VALUES (1(productpublicationID),1(ProductID),'Name1') ...it works. 
But when i try to 
INSERT INTO ProductPublication VALUES (1(productpublicationID),1(ProductID),'Name1'),
(2(productpublicationID),2(ProductID),'Name2'); ... it doens't work. 

I have to modify trigger so it works for multiple insert command.

Comment: Add into your question: complete textual code-formatted CREATE TABLE for both tables; Some initial data (3-5 rows per table) for both tables; INSERT INTO query; desired final data state (textual table-formatted).

Comment: @Akina , Thank you. It is my first time using stackoverflow. I edited my question.

Comment: Your CREATE TABLE scripts contains a lot of misprints. Please edit them.

Comment: I don't see your trigger code?

Comment: @Arvo Hello, i added the trigger script.

Comment: There is an error in the written code. An additional parenthesis. Please fix the code so that we can help you. this Line : `(SELECT Product_ID from inserted))`

Comment: @MostafaNZ i corrected the script, now it is working. But, there is no mistake in code. My mentor told me that whole trigger needs to be edited in order to work on multiple insert commands, that was my question. Thank you all.

Comment: Your problem is in this line `(SELECT Product_ID from inserted)`. This line of code loads multiple records. But you have used `Product_ID =` . The subquery should be written in such a way that it loads only one row. `(SELECT ProductName from Product
      WHERE Product_ID = (SELECT Product_ID from inserted))`

Comment: @MostafaNZ How should i change that line to load only one row? The last part of the code you wrote is the same as i wrote it in question. Thank you.

Comment: @MostafaNZ I solved this issue. Thank you so much for pointing out to me what the issue was. I will add the correct trigger to the question.

Comment: your work is excellent